# Use Matlab to determine the point of intersection of lines

Tags: matlab

I want to determine the point of intersection of two lines using Matlab. I have the two lines in the form of

y = tan(theta)*x + c.

I'm seeking an algorithm that does this and I already know how linear equations are solved manually to determine the point of intersection. I would like to know how its done using Matlab. 
And also, what must I do if I have to determine the point of intersection for more than two lines using Matlab?

Thanks

Comment: Write your system of equations in matrix notation as $ Az=b $. Solve it in Matlab using z=A\b;

Answer (score 1):

You want to solve the system of equations
\begin{align}
\tan(\theta_1) x - y &= -c_1 ,\\
\tan(\theta_2) x - y &= -c_2 \\
\end{align}
for $x$ and $y$.
This system can be written in matrix notation as
\begin{equation}
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
\tan(\theta_1) & -1 \\
\tan(\theta_2) & -1
\end{bmatrix}
}_{A}
\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}
= \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} -c_1 \\ -c_2 \end{bmatrix}}_{b}.
\end{equation}
In Matlab, this linear system of equations can be solved with the command

```
z = A\b;
```

If you have more than two lines, and you know they all intersect in a single point $(x,y)$, then we will have more equations and $A$ will have more rows (one row for each line).
We can find a least squares solution to
\begin{equation}
A \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = b,
\end{equation}
again using the Matlab command z = A\b;